# With NG-File-Upload what is a angular way of clearning the input type="file" after a successful upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

Using the library here https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload. What is a angular way or clearing the input file from the element after a successful upload? (so it goes back to saying "No file selected")

```
<input ng-file-select ng-model="vm.files" name="filename" accept="*" type="file" ng-file-change="vm.checkFileSize($files)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reset the model vm.files to the initial value - the empty array, the view will also reset to it's initial state.